# ColumnChooser free-jqgrid is not working on IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

After upgrade of my application from **jqGrid 4.6** to **free-jqgrid 4.8** the columnChooser functionality is not working. It's only on IE9. Demo is available here: http://jsfiddle.net/2tkkqbeq/15/ (Please open it in IE9 mode). 
The problem I think is in **apply_perm function** in jqGrid library:

```
   apply_perm: function () {
        var perm = [];
        $("option", select).each(function () {
            if ($(this).is("[selected]")) {
                $self.jqGrid("showCol", colModel[this.value].name);
            } else {
                $self.jqGrid("hideCol", colModel[this.value].name);
            }
        });
    }
```

When I changed `if ($(this).is("[selected]"))` to `if ($(this).is(":selected"))` it started to work.

What is the difference between `is("[selected]")` and `is[":selected"]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the bug report! I like questions with the demo which can be used to reproduce the problem.

It's the bug in jqGrid 4.7 (see [the line](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.7.0/js/grid.jqueryui.js#L222) and compare it with [the corresponding line](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.6.0/js/grid.jqueryui.js#L184) of jqGrid 4.6). The best test for selected option is the usage of `.is(":selected")`. The corresponding implementation of jQuery uses all specifics of the implementation in different version of web browsers. The selector `.is("[selected]")` means that the `selected` attribute exist with some value. Typically the attribute `selected` should have the value `"selected"` (`selected="selected"`). My test using your demo shows that in case of IE9 one have `selected=""` value and the test `.is("[selected]")` returns wrong value `true` instead of `.is(":selected")` provides the correct value `false`.

I fixed the line in the code of free jqGrid and additionally the close selector `$("option[selected]", select)` to `$("option", select).filter(":selected")`.

I posted the fix to github. Because you use in your demo the URL `//rawgit.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/master/js/jquery.jqgrid.src.js` then the demo will uses the modified code now. You can verify that it works correctly now in IE9.

Answer (score -1):

I have problem related to this filter :selected.
Also in demo, if you remove a column and immediately readd the column without closing columnchooser, the column remain hidden because $(this).is(":selected") return false (and I can't understand the reason but this happen both in chrome and edge where I have tested it)
If i use instead [selected] it works...